# Internet addicted, need software to control my usage and block access

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, internet

I found I have problem to be a little addictive with surfing on internet.

I am trying to find a free ware, (or software), that can help me for exemple to be just 2 hours per day on internet.

Like it is counting the minutes and than stop working. not just 2 hours in one time, but in whole day....

maybe that it has different modes (2hours together, in whole day, 2hours + little reserve time)

but I need something that really take me away access from internet :) Just counting time, is not enough for me :)

Hope we will find something because, I just can't avoid not to loose 4 hours on internet.

I have windows 7

Comment: Related: [xkcd blog: Distraction Affliction Correction Extension](http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/18/distraction-affliction-correction-extensio/)

Comment: unplug the router ;)

Comment: @user69991, what browser? Most browsers have extensions available to manage and monitor the time you spend on various sites and provide graphs and charts. They also allow you to specify how much time you want to spend on them and will block you after that time has elapsed (they usually give you a warning and a chance to finish up what you’re doing or hit the ‘snooze’). Do a search for ‘time management’ extensions for your browser.

Comment: If you are addicted, won't you just disable anything that you set up? That is like hiding your cigarettes when you are trying to quit smoking. Seek professional help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Firefox, you can use [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/leechblock/) to restrict internet access. You can set rules for specific sites (or all sites) with the extension and block sites after a certain time or at a certain time of the day.

More info: http://www.proginosko.com/leechblock.html

Comment: :) great answers, but

in first answer is problem, that I use 80% Chrome, but hmm I found StayFocused

Comment: is there a software for windows, not just plugin for browser. because if it bloks on firefoex and chrome....i will automaticly open opera :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem!

I also have multiple browsers so a firefox only solution would not work.

I found I was browsing a select few sites repeatedly - youtube/bbc news etc.
There is a text file called "hosts" (without any extension) which you can edit 
with a text editor (run as admin) to block specific sites. So for example to block youtube and facebook you can add

```
127.0.0.1       www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1       www.facebook.com
```

to the file.
To re-allow access you can comment out the lines with '#' like so:

```
#127.0.0.1       www.youtube.com
#127.0.0.1       www.facebook.com
```

Now you can manually edit-in or edit-out all the '#' characters to block-unblock your wasteful browsing. I actually I wrote a small program to remove the # characters so that I could block everything with a single icon click. But I deliberately didn't write a program to do the reverse. So I can block everything in half a second and its a clumsy manual editing job (removing all the #'s) to start browsing again.

Comment: +1 Good idea! The path to the file is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (on Vista, 7 should be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Get a DD WRT capable router, and install DD WRT on it - [it has an option for blocking your internet.](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Restrictions)

Get someone else to set the password, and have them write it down and put it in a sealed envelope 
In addition, put it the router and the modem in a lockable cabinet, and give the keys to someone who lives far enough that getting the keys would only be a viable option if internet totally goes out.If you break into the cabinet for your fix...

Comment: it is great but a little to strict.. what IF one day I will need a lot more internet (different work project)...

Comment: well, the 'social' aspects of the fix are as important as the 'technical' side - get the password, change the settings, and get the password changed and secured again.

Comment: I was about to suggest this myself. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario in its simplest form is fairly easy to control:  one device with only one way to connect to the internet.  Just use one of the aforementioned tools.

However, there are desktops, laptops, netbooks, pads, phones and other gadgets galore that provide a means to surf.   Plus, the fact that you can get a signal from most public places (or lazy neighbors) will make it even more difficult to monitor.

Unless you're in the unlikely bubble of the first use case, you will be limited by your own self-control.

Maybe approaching the situation from a different angle would help you cope.  When you're surfing, ask yourself "Is this website constructive for me?"

If you're browsing any of the 43 Stack Exchange sites, then the answer is probably yes.  If you're watching Jersey Shore vids on YouTube, then the answer is probably no.

I don't think there's a magic time unit that determines addicted/non-addicted.  In fact, as someone who wakes up and goes to sleep connected, it's either very normal to stay online constantly or I'm just a functional addict. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called "WatchDog" that some school districts use to limit students' time on the internet.    It is neither free nor prohibitively expensive.  I have not used this program (my computer has an "off" switch), so I cannot give you much more details about it.  This may be what you are looking for if you have difficulty finding the "off" switch on your computer.